# Retrieve date specific XYZ tiles of Bing or ESRI for QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online-basemaps, bing-maps, xyz-tiles, world-imagery

The latest version of Bing XYZ imagery has this link, [http://ecn.t3.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a{q}.jpeg?g=1](http://ecn.t3.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a%7Bq%7D.jpeg?g=1), which has been updated few months back. But I want to access url of previous year or previous version. Is there any way we can obtain that url.
Similarly for ESRI imagery, https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D this is the link. Can we obtain link for previous version? Will it require change in url?